# SSIS Script task AcquireConnection returns Null

Tags: c#, ssis, sqlconnection, oledbconnection

In SSIS I have a connection defined with the following connection string:

```
Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=Spears;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;
```

i am attempting to use this connection from a script task:

```
ConnectionManager connectionManager = this.Dts.Connections["Spears"];
object acquireConnection = connectionManager.AcquireConnection(this.Dts.Transaction);
SqlConnection con = acquireConnection as SqlConnection;
con.Open();
```

On execution

- **connectionManager** comes back as a fully populated ConnectionManager
  object
- **acquireConnection** is a System._ComObject
- **con** is null
- obviously opening con fails

Casting as OleDbConnection or OdbcConnection returns null as well.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Check if `acquireConnection` variable is null. If it is not, then casting it to **SqlConnection** fails, since you are doing `as SqlConnection` operation.
Also check this [example from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136018.aspx), according to it, you have to create SQLConnection first and then assign.

Comment: Were you able to use this approach? In my case `Dts.Transaction` is null and I have the same problem. I didn't want to use the connection string approach, but that may be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because you are using an **OLEDB** connection in the SSIS package instead of an **ADO.NET** one.

Once you change that, the code should work fine, even if `Dts.Transaction` is null.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.  First, you have not instantiated new SqlConnection object as in `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();`

Second, unless the container is set to participate in a transaction, Dts.Transaction will be null and so the cast to a SqlConnection will be null.  Transactions are supported by default, but unless a parent container starts it, there will be no shared transaction.  This makes the examples from MS a little misleading.

I suggest going with the following.  Supposing your connection manager is an OleDb connection, the add System.Data.Oledb to the usings:

```
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Dts.Connections[".\\sql2016.SSISAuditDB"].ConnectionString);
    using (conn)
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT 1", conn);
        int val = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MessageBox.Show(val.ToString());
    }
```

In the above code, we just grab the connection string from our connection manager and then create a new connection from it.  Note that OleDbConnection implements IDisposable, so it can be wrapped in a using() block and it does not need to be explicitly closed.  This is a good practice, because it means you will not need to have extra handling for closing the connection, for example if you added a catch block.

m

Comment: Thank you, this solution got me half way to a working solution. When I try to open the connection, I get the following: "Login failed for user 'usernameHere'". This is odd because the same connection in Connection Manager works outside this Script Task. Any ideas or help?

Comment: That _is_ odd!  You are using integrated security I your example. It may be that passwords are wiped out by ssis. You can try storing the connection string in a variable and parameterize that if it works.

Comment: Why would he need to create a `new SqlConnection()` if `con` will have what `AcquireConnection` returns?

Comment: @Andrew you are correct, the transaction object returned from the `AcquireConnection` method could be cast to a SqlConnection.  For the reasons I noted about the transaction being null, I found it easier to create a new object.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You're using SQLNCLI11.1 Provider with SqlConnection object. Change your DTS connection, use "ADO.NET Connection" and try it.